# Properties Pages dialog box for ImageList

Tags: vba

I am working on a legacy excel vba application and I need to modify/add images to an existing imagelist but I can't find how to access the Property Pages dialog. I guess something is wrong with my pc configuration or some dll issue.

I created a new form in a new worksheet and the same problem:

[image]

If I click in Properties:

[image]

How I can show the property pages dialog to add/delete/modify images on the listview? Is there any hotkey or option in a menu? I just can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the GUI actually works in VBA as it does in VB6. The class `{7EBDAAE1-8120-11CF-899F-00AA00688B10}` is probably not registered on your machine.

> You need to manually register the Msstkprp.dll file. Step-by-Step
>   Procedure
>
> Copy the Msstkprp.dll file from \OS\System folder on your Visual Basic
>   CD to your Windows\System folder (or the System32 folder if you are
>   using Microsoft Windows NT). Use the RegSvr32 utility to manually
>   register the Msstkprp.dll. On the Windows Start menu, click Run, and
>   then type the following command: Regsvr32
>   C:\Windows\System\Msstkprp.dll

Info comes from [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/188331).

[This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c89aca63-25d7-43b9-bc14-6bf3e1cb440e/excel-vba-listview-clicking-custom-property-generates-class-not-registered-error?forum=isvvba) lists some other alternatives.